# how to use backgound image in a .s4-title-inner(CSS)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I'm doing some branding and i need to have a background image in a top header above the menu.I tried :

```
.s4-title-inner{
background-image:url('../../images/cj-intranet-bkg.png');
/*When i use a normal color it works*/
*/
}
```

But no luck any ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `background:url` in your custom CSS file, it should make it work for you:

```
.s4-title{
    background:url("/Style Library/MyImages/SomeImage.png") repeat-x left top;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add something like this -

background-image: url(../Site%20Pictures/internal.png) **!important**; -- without the single quotes.

or simply use

background:url(../images/blackBullet.gif) **!important**;

Since this class is being used in corev4.css, the ' **!important** ' tag helps in overwriting it. Check also for the path of the image being referred.

Comment: I would advise against using !important, and load your CSS *after* corev4.css using `CssRegistration`. If your selector is correct it'll cascade properly.

Comment: Thanks @JamesLove for reminding this. I agree on using the 'after corev4.css' on CSSRegistration.

Comment: As James points out, you should never use !important. SharePoint typically uses the "background" property as opposed to "background-image". In order to override the OOTB SharePoint styles, you must use the same property combined with a selector of the same specificity. If you use ".s4-title {background: xyz;}" and load after the corev4.css, you'll override the default style.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the "s4-title-inner" class you need to use, but the "s4-title" class (if you want to change the background for the title section, otherwise you need to use the "s4-titlerow" ID).

Normally you do not need to add the "!important" attribute when your stylesheet is loaded after corev4.css.